# gatsby HTML file size too large (i.e. due to bootstrap-CSS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, gatsby

### Problem

When I build my gatsby website with "gatsby build", the size of the generated HTML and CSS **files is fairly large** (approx. 200kB; even though there is close to zero real text-content in it).

When looking into the generated HTML-file, it turns out, that in **each and every** generated HTML-file, the complete global CSS is (in text-form) included. So it is completly redundant.

In my case: I use **bootstrap** as frontend framework, so all the bootstrap-css-classes (used and unused ones) are

1. 100% included in the generated HTML-files
2. AND additionally: in the seperate  "styles.ac6d....css" file.

To clarify: What I get after the gatsby built:

```
index.html    210 kB
about.html    210 kB
imprint.html  210 kB
....
style.css     200 kB
```

### Expected Behaviour

What I would have expected after the gatsby built:

```
index.html     10 kB
about.html     10 kB
imprint.html   10 kB
....
style.css     200 kB
```

I would like to have small HTML-files without any unused CSS in it **OR** at least not to have the CSS redundently in 20 different files.

### Questions

1. Is it possible to get gatsby built HTML-files without all CSS redundently included in every file?
2. AND / OR: Is it possible to have only the needed CSS-classes in the file (especially in the case of **bootstrap**)?
3. Am I doing something wrong here?

### Additional Infos

**How do I import the bootstrap CSS?**

in global.scss:

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap
```

in gatsby-browser.js

```
import "./src/styles/global.scss"
```

**How does the compiled HTML look like?**

The compiled HTML in index.html (and about.html, ...) from gatsby looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/><style data-href="/styles.ac6d966df9cf852917cd.css" id="gatsby-global-css">/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.6.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2021 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f42c1;--pink:#e83e8c;--red:#dc3545;--orange:#fd7e14;--yellow:#ffc107;
 
 <!-- .... [ALL THE REST OF BOOTSTRAP CSS] -->
```

---

### Edit: Conclusion for me

To inject the full global CSS in all the HTML files seems to be a normal behavior from the gatsby build process according to the comments. So just in case anybody else wonders about this gatsby behaviour...

Comment: How are you importing the styles and Bootstrap in your components?

Comment: @FerranBuireu: I import it with: "@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";" in my **global.scss**. This is what I found in the docs. Is there a better way to do it in your eyes?

Comment: Where is this `global.scss` imported and how?

Comment: @FerranBuireu: sorry for my uncomplete answer. It gets importet in "gatsby-browser.js" with: import "./src/styles/global.scss" (according to the docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/)

Comment: I think you have a problem in your thinking, If you want to spare some kb, there is only purgecss or my approach with using fine granular bootstrap modules. Thats it. There are no "other" options. If you want to be super lean on the CSS front, then use tailwindCSS, there you have purging right baked into.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the SCSS way by importing a global **styles.scss** in which you only import the needed parts of the bootstrap distribution.

```
/*----------------------------------------------------
 Overriden Bootstrap Variables (by me!!!!!)
------------------------------------------------------*/
$primary: #00B056;
$secondary: #bf9571;

$body-bg: #fff;
$body-color: #5a5a5a;

/*----------------------------------------------------
 Import Bootstrap SCSS
------------------------------------------------------*/

// use this one only for debugging purposes. This is the whole package
//@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Required
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Optional
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images"; 

// add more bootstrap stuff as needed
```

There are of course more partial scss bootstrap packages available. Check their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) for scss handling or check your node_modules path.

Of course you need to install bootstrap via npm/yarn to have it available. Also you need gatsby scss plugins like **gatsby-plugin-sass** and **node-sass**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Even if this will reduce the total amount of CSS inserted into the HTML files, it will **not** avoid the redundandy, correct? And it will still insert the CSS into the HTML, right?

Comment: yep, this is the way to go

Comment: another option is to not use Bootstrap :P :P :P

Comment: @George: thank you! not using bootstrap makes me unhappy; but having 20 times the same CSS inserted into my HTML-files makes me unhappy as well :(

Comment: Don’t get the redudancy thing though.

Comment: @Logemann: with redundancy I mean: the CSS is (as real code) inserted into index.html, about.html, contact.html, etc. **and additionally** it can be found in style.css. For me it would be logical to **only** have the code once in style.css and import it in the HTML. But according to your comments this seems to be normal behaviour from gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

Among not using Bootstrap as [@George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4375751/george) suggested in [@Logemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614659/logemann)'s answer, which in my opinion should be always avoided because tend to overload the applications and the same effect can be easily applied using own custom CSS.

I would suggest only importing the mandatory Bootstrap modules, rather than all the dependency to save some KB.

In addition, if get rid of Bootstrap is not an option I will try to look at some purging plugin, such as [`gatsby-plugin-purcecss`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-purgecss/) to remove some duplicated styles in specific files.

```
// gatsy-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-stylus`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-less`,
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    // Add after these plugins if used
    { 
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-purgecss`,
      options: {
        printRejected: true, // Print removed selectors and processed file names
        // develop: true, // Enable while using `gatsby develop`
        // tailwind: true, // Enable tailwindcss support
        // whitelist: ['whitelist'], // Don't remove this selector
        // ignore: ['/ignored.css', 'prismjs/', 'docsearch.js/'], // Ignore files/folders
        // purgeOnly : ['components/', '/main.css', 'bootstrap/'], // Purge only these files/folders
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: My answer does exactly that. Picking only the needed bootstrap modules.

Comment: Yes, didn't mean to override your question (that's why I referenced you), just adding an extra workaround (using the PurgeCSS) + some personal suggestions :)